# Python, virtualenv and dylib

Tags: python, virtualenv, dylib

I would like to have a custom Python inside a `virtualenv` that provides a `libpythonX.X.dylib` which I can use in Xcode to link against Python. When I make a virtualenv I find the libpythonX.X.dylib in myEnv/lib/pythonX.X/config. But it is a symlink only which points to the globally installed Python that does not have the site-packages that are installed exclusively in my virutalenv. So how can I make up a virtualenv that provides a *correct* libpythonX.X.dylib?

Comment: libpython.dylib doesn't change when site packages are installed. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I like to execute Python scripts from a Cocoa app. But giving Xcode the dylib from my virtualenv results in an error that packages are not installed that are only installed in the virutalenv but not globally. I thought the reason must be the .dylib because it points to the global Python which does not have these packages installed.

Comment: @mipadi And I followed [Apples Technical Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2328/_index.html) to link against Python.

Comment: The dylib only contains code for the Python interpreter, not installed modules—you'll have to install those and make sure that paths are set up properly so the Python interpreter you're using can find them.

Comment: @mipadi In the activated virtualenv, I tested that I can use the modules (for example numpy). What I have to give to Xcode is the dylib and the header search path which I set to `myVirtualEnv/include/pythonX.X`. This does't work. The output in Xcode is that the package numpy does not exist but it certainly does!

Comment: You have to package the entire virtualenv with the app, and when you run the Python interpreter, you have to add the site-packages folder to the PYTHONPATH environment variable. Python modules are not packaged as part of a dylib.

Comment: @mipadi Thanks. It is not necessary to package the entire virtualenv with the app. Setting the PYTHONPATH via `sys.path.append('path/to/site-packages/')` was enough to get it to work. Turn your comment to an answer and I can accept it.